# Structure of Go project

Tags: go, directory-structure

My program uses several files like *.json, *.db

How should i place they? First variant:

```
project
    |-> src
        |-> main
            | main.go
            | main_test.go
            |-> data
                | database.db
        |-> config
            | config.go
            |-> data
                | config.json
        ...
```

Or:

```
project
    |-> src
        |-> main
            | main.go
            | main_test.go
        |-> config
            | config.go
        ...
    |-> data
        | database.db
        | config.json
```

I would prefer second variant, but I get troubles when try to write tests. I tried to use "/absolute/path", but it doesn't work, because it points to ".../src/main/ folder.

Comment: You should probably start by reading through [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html). Go projects generally use a `testdata` directory for test data since that is ignored by the build tools. You should also _never_ have any non-test paths that are relative to the program source, as the location of the source is completely irrelevant to the working directory of the executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The go test command sets the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) to the directory containing the package source files. For example, the config tests are run with the working directory set to `project/src/config`:

Use paths relative to that directory from tests:

A test in the first variant should open files like this:

```
 f, err := os.Open("data/config.json")
 if err != nil {
     // handle error
 }
```

A test in the second variant should should open files like this:

```
 f, err := os.Open("../../data/config.json")
 if err != nil {
     // handle error
 }
```

(the important point here is the relative path, not that os.Open is used).

Comment: Does it meant that I should submit the path to function? For example, getConfig() -> getConfig(path). Now I have constant path in body of function.

Comment: Relative paths are resolved to an absolute path using the working directory.  There's no relationship between what the working directory might be and the source directory. In fact, the source directory may not be present locally when the application is run.  Pass a path as an argument or use an absolute path. It's usually easier to specify the path.